# Unknown X-MAC request header

Tags: javascript, request, request-headers

Hello I have found a parameter in my request header, but I don't know what it is.

Here I give you a sample of my header and the X-MAC parameter that is at the end:

```bash
authority: carper-example-api.examplecarper.com
method: POST
path: /auth/login
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8
content-length: 52
content-type: application/json
origin: https://play.example.com
referer: https://play.example.com/
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="106", "Google Chrome";v="106", "Not;A=Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
x-mac: CEcEdtgZ+hlSIDk+dM/58munhvmsBvQNV6xjDfwRhZ44Q2Ten7H87xtqk0QjFb42f9OKeMDvaTzkJSs/asspMbpRielgAVSYpBJihWn4T0N7XrqTVhhbFhpnTCRBx5Niaetq9BeVS54AP8dO7VMMs1N1A99tbnlLtmk3rSzxeZU=
```

Answer (score 0):

Did a little bit of research, it looks like it's a protocol for wireless sensor networks.

More can be found [here](https://dak664.github.io/contiki-doxygen/a00289_source.html), [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221091335_X-MAC_A_short_preamble_MAC_protocol_for_duty-cycled_wireless_sensor_networks) and [here](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/users-guide/ch-sensor-macs.html)

Comment: and which makes a serial like this from a protocol for wireless sensor networks in a requests header. What is the reason for this implementation?

Comment: tambien he encontrado este [link](https://doc.omnetpp.org/inet/api-current/neddoc/inet.linklayer.xmac.XMac.html) _italic_ **bold**